# list all components of an ARM computer in Linux?

Tags: debian, hardware, arm

I have an ARM based computer that seems to work alright running Ubuntu Linux (non GUI). How do I get a list of all the components that are on this computer ? like type of Ethernet chip, Wifi chip, Bluetooth, CPU, power management chip etc if possible.

Answer (score 12):

The variation of ARM implementations is too high to be covered with the standard tools.

Digging down `/sys/class` you will find all your components, but it's a pain to do so. You can't use `find /sys/class -name name` to find all the components because of the symbolic links. You neither can use `find -L` because of the circle links.

```
cat /sys/class/*/*/device/*/{,*/,*/*/}name */*/device/*/name|sort -u
```

gives you some impression of the devices, but if you really want to know the devices with actually loaded drivers, you will have to read manually through your `dmesg`.

Comment: Thanks Philippos. I'll spend some time with this and will report back.

Answer (score 9):

For listing hardware in IoT devices, usually the most useful commands after `dmesg` are `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and `lsusb`.

In most IoT brands, `lsusb` reveals itself useful, as for instance sinovoip (banana) tends to connect a lot of the hardware to the USB(s) controller(s).

As for listing ALL the components; that won't be possible. There are no reliable methods to list components connected via the GPIO or i2c standards.

See examples for the raspberry:

`cat /proc/cpuinfo`, besides listings all the cores/threads (4 of them here), lists at the end the chipset model, revision, and *in some boards*, the serial number. (you have to slide until the end to see it)

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
model name   : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS   : 38.40
Features   : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer   : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant   : 0x0
CPU part   : 0xd03
CPU revision   : 4

processor   : 1
model name   : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS   : 38.40
Features   : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer   : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant   : 0x0
CPU part   : 0xd03
CPU revision   : 4

processor   : 2
model name   : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS   : 38.40
Features   : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer   : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant   : 0x0
CPU part   : 0xd03
CPU revision   : 4

processor   : 3
model name   : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS   : 38.40
Features   : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer   : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant   : 0x0
CPU part   : 0xd03
CPU revision   : 4

Hardware   : BCM2709
Revision   : a02082
Serial      : 00000000xxxxxxxx
```

And `lsusb`:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05dc:a781 Lexar Media, Inc.
```

Comment: The OP mentioned "Ethernet chip, Wifi chip, Bluetooth, CPU, power management chip". I wouldn't connect any of those via USB. Ethernet I do mainly with PCIe, WLAN with SDIO or PCIe, Bluetooth with UART and PMIC with I2C/SMbus. It's a complex world down there ...

Comment: @Philippos I would not too...The problem is that many Chinese vendors do it in rpi clones due to cost factors - wifi via USB is fairly common. I tend to stay way from boards that implement Ethernet and SATA via USB.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't meet such. Maybe because I work with systems I designed myself. Now I remember I saw some 802.11ac modules with USB2 port and wondered why someone could want the fast standard with USB handbrake. (-X

Comment: Thank you Rui. I'll spend some time on these.

Appreciate the mini discussion between Philippos and Rui on this one. It provided me some useful insight on what to lookout for.
i'll report back after spending some time on this.

Answer (score 4):

ARM architecture don't have any PCI bus. They use AMBA bus.

[AMBA](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0138d/I8652.html)

[image: ARM Block Diagram]

Dmesg will give you most informations you need.

Comment: I don't know which device you are showing us, but there are many ARM SoCs out there with PCIe. Unfortunally most peripherals like the internal GPU don't use PCIe, so they won't show with `lspci`. So while the first part of your answer is wrong, the second is correct: `dmesg` is the way to go.

Comment: Not many, no. Only the [Juno](https://developer.arm.com/products/system-design/development-boards/juno-development-board) have PCI lanes. 

And you won't find it on any consumer available devices, as it never took off, too expensive to produce and not popular enough.

What you can see is Mini-PCIe slots. But they are driven by the USB Hub, there's no PCI bus at all. Like this ![one](http://www.cnx-software.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/PInBALL_Block_Diagram_Large.png). It won't be seen by lspci. 

But i am ready to be proven wrong, find me a consumer available one with PCIe lanes.

Comment: Only from the ARM SoCs I currently work with: The i.MX6 family by Freescale (--> NXP --> Qualcomm), probably the most widespread SoC in this class, has PCIe, as well TI's Sitara AM57* and AM5K* chips and Nvidia's Tegra K1 and Qualcomm's Snapdragon 600E. Consumers can get development boards or community boards or final devices (like some K1-based chromebooks) with those. So I disagree: Yes, many. Most in this class

Answer (score 1):

To list all components on a Linux system you can use:

- The `inxi` command with `-option` see `inxi -h`
- The `hwinfo` command similar to `lshw` and more detailled.
- the `/proc` directory which contains all the information about the system, memory, devices, hardware ....

Comment: Does `dmidecode` even work on ARM? Doesn't it rely on IBM PC BIOS standards?

Comment: @dirkt Not even a little bit. It only works on i386, x86_64, and some ia64 systems.

Answer (score 0):

The `lshw` command gives a pretty complete listing of your computer's components.

You can get it on Ubuntu with `apt-get install lshw`.

Comment: You did never run `lshw` on an arm box, did you? I never saw `lshw` provide even a third of the components known to the system via the device tree.